# Prove that $f$ is a choice function if and only if every finite subfunction of $f$ is a choice function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I'm trying to understand how Tukey Lemma implies AC. The proof relies on the above statement. It's not hard to see that if $f$ is a choice function then every finite subfunction of $f$ is a choice function, but I haven't been able to see why the other direction holds.

Comment: Have you tried to verify the definition of a function and then of a choice function?

Comment: $f$ is a choice function on $X$ if $\forall x\in X\colon f(x)\in x$. If $f|_A$ is a choice function for every finite subset $A$ of $X$, then in particular for $A=\{x\}$, $x\in X$. Hence $f(x)=f|_{\{x\}}(x)\in x$, as desired